# Firebase - Adapter is called before my array has any elements and returns an empty RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm facin a really weird problem, Im calling two nodes in my database , from one node I get all my user ids , then I just loop inside my user node to get the user metadata. The problem is that when I run the debugger, it seems like the mAdapter is beign called before the data is beign fetched. So my adapter set the recyclerview with no data. After the adapter has been called, my query fetching the user begins and the array is populated normally

This is what I have done so far

```
 mDatabase.child("teamsNode").child(teamID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

            mDatabase.child("users").child(snapshot.getKey()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    UserModel model = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);
                    String playerName = model.getName();
                    model.setName(playerName);
                    mArrayPlayers.add(model);
                }


                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }

            });

        }
        mAdapter = new PlayersAdapter(mArrayPlayers,mContext,R.layout.recycler_row);
        if(mAdapter.getItemCount()>0)
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }

});
```

As you can see, I set the adapter to the recyclerview after the first foreach that fetchs all the data, I know that beign asynchronous I need to wait for the inner mDatabase to be done but if I move the setting of the adapter one line above to wait for the second call to finish it does the same, any idea?

Database structure is like this

```
teamsNode
|__Jm2KSMjslpow2Ipoasz : true
|__601KSMjsldfjd2Ipos0 : true
|__asgm2Kshalpow2IposJ : true

users
|__Jm2KSMjslpow2Ipoasz 
   |_____name: randomname1
|__601KSMjsldfjd2Ipos0
   |_____name: randomname2
|__asgm2Kshalpow2IposJ
   |_____name: randomname3
```

Recyclerview is not populated. Any idea?

A weird thing is that sometimes runing it with the debugger does fill the data, but its rarely to happend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only initialize the adapter when all data is loaded, you will need to do so in the nested `onDataChange` callback:

```
mDatabase.child("teamsNode").child(teamID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshotTeam) {
        AtomicInteger loadedUserCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
        for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshotTeam.getChildren()){

            mDatabase.child("users").child(snapshot.getKey()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    UserModel model = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);
                    String playerName = model.getName();
                    model.setName(playerName);
                    mArrayPlayers.add(model);
                    if (loadedUserCount.getAndIncrement() + 1 == dataSnapshotTeam.getChildrenCount()) {
                        mAdapter = new PlayersAdapter(mArrayPlayers,mContext,R.layout.recycler_row);
                        if(mAdapter.getItemCount()>0) {
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { 
                    throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { 
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much Frank !

Comment: There is just one problem, that is sometimes it enters to  if (loadedUserCount.getAndIncrement() + 1 == dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()) { and sometimes not, do you think its because something ? because lets say , for the first row I press in my recycler , it enters to the second datasnapshot, but for the others dont

Comment: I have been looking at it, and it just works for the first element in the recyclerview

Comment: seems like loadedUserCount.getAndIncrement() + 1 == dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() are different when I press another element in my RecyclerView, it seems like loadedUserCount.getAndIncrement() + 1  this is 3 and datasnapshot.getchildrenCount() is 7

Comment: just solved it, the seocond dataSnapshot in the if statment was getting childrencound from my users nodes and not from the team nodes :)

Comment: Good catch, I didn't notice I was using the same names. Thanks for fixing it!

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that the calls to the `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` methods are asynchronous, so they are executed in another thread. When you call the second `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` this is executed in another thread, while the main thread follows its execution. You have to do the call of your adapter in the answer of your second call `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` in the `onDataChange` method. In this way to avoid anomalous operations of your application.

Comment: quote from the question "As you can see, I set the adapter to the recyclerview after the first foreach that fetchs all the data, I know that beign asynchronous I need to wait for the inner mDatabase to be done but if I move the setting of the adapter one line above to wait for the second call to finish it does the same, any idea?"

Comment: It is possible then that you are doing wrong the call to
mDatabase.child ("teamsNode"). child (teamID)
, since according to
json structure that you copied you only have:

teamsNode
| __Jm2KSMjslpow2Ipoasz: true
| __601KSMjsldfjd2Ipos0: true
| __asgm2Kshalpow2IposJ: true

and when doing child (teamID), you would only get the true value that you use as a key for your second call, check it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help.

```
mDatabase.child("teamsNode").child(teamID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    mArrayPalyer.clear();//add this
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                            mDatabase.child("users").child(snapshot.getKey()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                    UserModel model = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);
                                    String playerName = model.getName();
                                    model.setName(playerName);
                                    mArrayPlayers.add(model);
                                }



                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }

                            });

                        }
                        mAdapter = new PlayersAdapter(mArrayPlayers,mContext,R.layout.recycler_row);
                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter); //makes changes here because you are checking for adapter item count before setting it and this always return null.

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at my code I am using `ValueEventListener` just like you and binding the data to `recycler view`

```
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
               UserListModel userListModel =dataSnapshot1.getValue(UserListModel.class);
               userModelArrayList.add(userListModel);
           }
           userListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(">>value", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());

        }
    };
    //mDatabase is the reference to the Firebase Node
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(postListener);
    userListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(M.gridLayoutRecyclerView(getActivity() , 2));
    userListAdapter = new UserListAdapter(getActivity(), userModelArrayList);
    userListRecyclerView.setAdapter(userListAdapter);
```